# View values of Redis PubSub channel

Tags: redis

I have few questions, I could not find the answers from Redis tutorial

1) how can I view/check values of a Redis PubSub channel? `Monitor` command is there to debug Redis, but I want to check what previously has pushed to channel.

2) What is the exact differece between channel and a queue?

3) how can I monitor Redis cluster in a free web based application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You cannot view/check values that were  published on a channel in the past. You can think of pubsub as fire and forget. Redis publishes a messages on a channel to clients which have subscribed to it, but does not persist the message for future reference. You can only monitor the messages published in realtime

2) Channel is a reference used by Redis to know which clients have subscribed to received messages published on that channel.

Queue is a data structure which stores values, these values can be accessed in future in FIFO order. So if you are using a queue for messaging, the messages will remain in the queue until you explicitly delete them

3) IMO there isn't any great free monitoring tool for Redis out there. See some available options [here](https://haydenjames.io/using-redis-stat-for-redis-statistics-tracking/)

As a side, regarding questions 1) and 2) : in case you are looking for reliable messaging, check out Redis Streams.